# Position View based on where LinearLayout children touch

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have a layout like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONQ1o.png). Colored green is a horizontal LinearLayout, blue is a vertical LinearLayout and black are EditTexts (whose width and height can change). The red line represents where the EditTexts in the blue LinearLayout touch.

What I'm trying to accomplish is align the outer EditTexts so that the red line is always in the vertical center of them. On the image it already looks like that since I set the layout's gravity to center, but my issue occurs when the height of one of the EditTexts in the blue layout is bigger that the other. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH8Jv.png), but in reality it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQcKO.png).

What I'm trying to achieve can be accomplished with ConstraintLayouts by constraining the outer EditText's top to the bottom of the top inner (inner meaning those which used to be in the blue layout) EditText and the bottom to the top of the bottom inner EditText, but then there are other issues

- All EditTexts would be in the same layout which messes with the code a lot
- You can constrain the end/start to only one other View and so one of the inner EditTexts would overlap the outer one (e.g. if the outer EditText was constrained to the top inner EditText, the bottom inner EditText would overlap the outer one if it were wider than the top one) [Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8GwZ.png)
- Every View is created dynamically so using LinearLayouts makes locating each one way easier

How would you approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use just the XML for the layout you have to center the external *EditTexts* to the red line. *ConstraintLayout* is the way to go but, if that is not desirable, then you can apply translation to the external *EditTexts*. The idea is that you would measure the vertical location of the red line and the top position of each *EditText*. You would then apply enough translation in the Y direction to place the *EditTexts* where you want them

Se [setTranslationY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTranslationY(float)) and [getY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getY()).